# How to remove the extension in a string

Tags: awk, sed

I have strings in my file which has this format (input):

```
    abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)

    asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)

    asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

    asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)

    shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
```

output:

```
   abchsfk/jshflka                     cell

    asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf                 mob

    asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf     cel

    asjhdjs/jhskjds                     abc

    shdsjk/jhskd                        xyz
```

I want to remove Z, ZN and LVT in the string.

I tried with `sed 's/LVT//g' <filename>` and `sed 's/Z*//g' <filename>`.

Comment: I tried using this command

           sed 's/LVT//g' <filename>   and 


           sed 's/Z*//g' <filename>

Answer (score 1):

sed with regex enabled will do

```
sed -r 's_/Z|\(|LVT\)|/ZN__g'
```

note that you're also removing open parenthesis and the other strings as `/Z`,`/ZN`, and `LVT)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this (but use `sed` like [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa) showed will be strongly recommend):

```
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f1:
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            # replace ZN should be do first (only for ZN and Z, not for others)
            line = line.replace('/ZN', '')
            line = line.replace('/Z', '')
            line = line.replace('(', '')
            line = line.replace('LVT', '')
            line = line.replace(')', '')
            f2.write(line)
```

Comment: @ Fei. Thank you for the idea. I want to write a perl script for that. I have other things to do in the same file. your idea is helpful.